# Is there a way to shortcut an "or" statement in Excel formulas, similar to javascript?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Javascript you can use the expression `a||b`. If `a` is empty then this resolves to whatever is in `b`, otherwise whatever is in `a`.

Is there a similar technique in Excel's formula logic?

Instead of saying `=if(a<>"",a,b)` a way to say `=or(a,b)` or something similar to avoid the if statement. It would shorten the formula some and is more intuitive for someone with a js background. I tried `or(a,b)` and it doesn't work, so maybe someone's found another way.

For example,

if a = "" and b = "", then the result should be "".
if a = "abc" and b = "", then the result should be "abc".
If a = "" and b = "def", then the result should be "def".
If a = "abc" and b = "def", then the result should be "abc" since it's first.

It's also a way to set up defaults. If a = "" then it uses b "def".

Comment: A little context would be nice. Sample data and expected results. The example shows a pretty short formula already, so the need to shorten seems not relevant. Do you need to validate more than 2 cells in reality?

Comment: What happens if both a and b are ""?

Comment: As to length of the formula, a||b is four characters in javascript with no repetition of variable use.   if(a<>"",a,b) is 13 chars.  So the if statement is 13/4  = 3x longer.   The point is that a||b is a simple expression, vs  "if then else" and repeating the use of the "a" variable in if(a<>"",a,b) formula.

Comment: Given your question and example, there isn't a simpler expression for it in Excel.

Comment: You want the `IFBLANK` function. Unfortunately, while there are both [`ISERROR`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/is-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665) and [`IFERROR`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611), there's only `ISBLANK` and no `IFBLANK`.

Comment: There could be, if you were to write a [LAMBDA](https://exceljet.net/functions/lambda-function) function using the `ISBLANK()` function

Comment: But with given example writing a lambda is overkill. I don't even see the problem with the IF function here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a name in the Name Manager. Since OR is already taken, use something else, like _OR

[image]

Then use it in your spreadsheet as a regular function:

[image]

Comment: The answer is a valid workaround as it delivers a shorter way to compare two values.  I wanted to propose to write your own custom public function in a VBA module - always possible.  However, you can't shorten it as much as in JS.  I believe that VBA is just stricter than JS.